# Why is PHP messing with my CSS?

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, contact-form

I created my contact form and have been using bootstrap for the CSS. My contact form looked great before I added the PHP, all fields aligned and they were centred. Now I have input my PHP the contact form it looks different. The field widths have shortened, the message box is a different width to the other fields and the forms is about 3/8’s across accross the screen. Before I added the PHP it was the width of 6 columns and centred, as you can see from my code.

I am new to web development and I am trying to learn the basics as I think it will help with my career in the future, so any help would be much appreciated. Also, I do have this hosted and live so there is definitely an error in my code somewhere.

This is my contact form with the PHP code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contactform" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" novalidate>
<?php
    if($sent === true) {
        echo "<h2 class='success'>Thanks, your message has been sent successfully</h2>";
    } elseif ($hasError === true) {
        echo '<ul class="errorlist">';
        foreach($errorArray as $key => $val) {
            echo "<li>" . ucfirst($key) . " field error - $val</li>";
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo (isset($name) ? $name : ""); ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

I then have other fields here almost identical for phone, email and message and then finish it off with the close form.

```
</form>
```

This is my j query script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jquery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#contactform").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your name",
                minlength: "Your name seems a bit short"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            message: {
                required: "Please enter your message"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You more than likely need to analyse the output HTML in full and work out what is missing.

Comment: PHP will not mess with CSS.

Comment: What do you mean by output html?

Comment: @graham if you were to view the source code on your php form in your browser then compare this to the the code before you added php there should be something missing/wrong for it to cause this type of problem.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven’t closed your errors list properly.

```php
echo '<ul class="errorlist">';
foreach($errorArray as $key => $val) {
    echo "<li>" . ucfirst($key) . " field error - $val</li>";
}
echo '</li>';
```

Should be…

```php
echo '<ul class="errorlist">';
foreach($errorArray as $key => $val) {
    echo "<li>" . ucfirst($key) . " field error - $val</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

(Notice the last line, changing `</li>` to `</ul>`.)

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have done this but it hasn't made any visual changes

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try template syntax? Your text editor will show you better syntax colors this way:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contactform" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" novalidate>
<?php if($sent === true): ?>
      <h2 class='success'>Thanks, your message has been sent successfully</h2>
<?php elseif ($hasError === true): ?>
        <ul class="errorlist">
            <?php foreach($errorArray as $key => $val): ?>
                <li><?php echo ucfirst($key); ?>  field error - <?php echo $val; ?></li>            
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
<?php endif;?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo (isset($name) ? $name : ""); ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```